# Uninstalling msmq causes msi created using Wix to fail

Tags: wix, msmq, uninstallation

I have a component in my wix project which installs a message queue on installation.  When trying to uninstall it fails with the error in the log:

```
MSI (s) (D8!C8) [15:55:10:618]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1062) of type 790531 for thread 4552
MessageQueuingExecuteUninstall: Queue: .\private$\myqueue
MSI (s) (D8!C8) [15:55:10:666]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1062) of type 790531 for thread 4552
MSI (s) (D8!C8) [15:55:10:688]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1063) of type 790531 for thread 4552
MessageQueuingExecuteUninstall:  Error 0x80070032: Domain SIDs not supported
MSI (s) (D8!C8) [15:55:10:717]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1063) of type 790531 for thread 4552
MSI (s) (D8!C8) [15:55:10:734]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1064) of type 790531 for thread 4552
MessageQueuingExecuteUninstall:  Error 0x80070032: Failed to get SID for account name
MSI (s) (D8!C8) [15:55:10:766]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1064) of type 790531 for thread 4552
MSI (s) (D8!C8) [15:55:10:784]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1065) of type 790531 for thread 4552
MessageQueuingExecuteUninstall:  Error 0x80070032: Failed to remove message queue permission
MSI (s) (D8!C8) [15:55:10:816]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1065) of type 790531 for thread 4552
MSI (s) (D8!C8) [15:55:10:833]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1066) of type 790531 for thread 4552
MessageQueuingExecuteUninstall:  Error 0x80070032: Failed to remove message queue permissions
MSI (s) (D8!C8) [15:55:10:867]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1066) of type 790531 for thread 4552
CustomAction MessageQueuingExecuteUninstall returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (s) (D8:3C) [15:55:10:901]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1061) of type 790536 for thread 4964
```

My Wix code looks like the following:

```
<util:User Id="myUser" Domain="[DOMAIN]" Name="[USERNAME]" CreateUser="no" RemoveOnUninstall="no" FailIfExists="no"/>
<msmq:MessageQueue Id='myQueue' Label='My Queue' Transactional='yes' PathName='[QUEUE_NAME]'>
<msmq:MessageQueuePermission Id='myQueuePermission' User='myUser' QueueGenericAll='yes' QueueGenericRead='yes' QueueGenericWrite='yes' QueueGenericExecute='yes'/>
```

I'm running the install/uninstall under the same user that is having the permissions set on the queue.

Anywone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error is "Error 0x80070032: Domain SIDs not supported".
To me that says you can't use a domain account to do whatever you are doing.
Does the same error occur if you use a local account to create/remove the queue?

Comment: did you tried creating msmq manually? if yes were you able to create it?

Comment: @Sunil manually i can create and remove a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. The only change is pathname. I think you need to use variable name instead of wixtest.

```
<Component ... >
    <util:User Id="GroupUsers" Domain="[LOGONDOMAIN]" Name="Users" CreateUser="no" FailIfExists="no" RemoveOnUninstall="no" />
    <msmq:MessageQueue PathName=".\Private$\wixtest" Label="My Test Queue" Id="MyTestQueue" >
        <msmq:MessageQueuePermission User="GroupUsers" Id="MyTestQueuePerm" PeekMessage="yes" ReceiveMessage="yes" WriteMessage="yes" />
    </msmq:MessageQueue > 
</Component>
```

Comment: The property set in the path name has a value similar to what you have stated.  The first line of the error in the log shows that it has read the path name correctly from the property as .\private$\myqueue